Is there a workaround to sending a POST request on tab close
I currently need the functionality to unlock a deal when the tab is closed, the issue is that the lock status is stored in my DB and i need to call a POST request on tab close which will set the status of the deal to unlocked. I tried using "beforeunload" but it is very unreliable as shared by others facing same problem(totally fails in my case). What are some workaround ways where i can send the api call. I am using Angular, C# ASP.NetCore, SQL
I have tried using beforeunload which fails, the tab close should trigger the API call

Well, based on your scenario, you can use the navigator.sendBeacon API to send an asynchronous POST request during the tab's unload event, as it's more dependable than the beforeunload event. Additionally, consider implementing a server-side fallback mechanism like a heartbeat or session expiry, which automatically unlocks the deal after a period of inactivity if the client fails to send the request. Combining these approaches ensures that the deal is unlocked even if the tab close event doesn't trigger the API call successfully.

I second sendBeacon suggestion... also trigger on pagehide or visibilitychange which should be more reliable.  None of those events will cover all scenarios.  DB "locks" in general are problematic.

You can try creating a ng service and adding an eventListener to the 'unload' event; after that you can use the navigator.sendBeacon() method. Something like this:

export class UnloadService {

  constructor() {
    window.addEventListener('unload', this.sendUnlockRequest);
  }

  sendUnlockRequest = () => {
    const url = '/api/unlock-deal';
    const data = JSON.stringify({ dealId: 'your-deal-id' });
    navigator.sendBeacon(url, data);
  }
}
 


Have you considered using Websocket? You can establish a connection when the page is opened and have the backend detect when the page is closed, triggering the POST request.
The reason is that when the browser process is closed directly, the unload lifecycle event is not triggered. However, WebSocket allows the backend to detect if the connection is lost.
